# WPF Datagrid AlternatingRowBackground

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Lets assume I have an object

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public String Note { get; set; }
```

And I have the following code to bind it to datagrid:

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = _db.Notes.ToList().OrderBy(d => d.EmployeeId);
```

Is it possible to use `AlternatingRowBackground=""  AlternationCount=""` of the datagrid to set row colors alternation based on `EmployeeId`?

Comment: What do you mean by _based on EmployeeId_? From the sound of the variable name, it sounds like this property would be unique -- in which are you asking if you can make every row unique colors? Because I'm not sure how you're intending it to work.

Comment: @Chris `EmployeeId` is a foreign key to Employee Table.

Comment: So you want multiple rows in the same color as long as they share the same employee id and alternate the color for the next group of rows?

Comment: That didn't answer my question at all unfortunately so it's kind of difficult to answer your question; it would help if you could be more descriptive with your responses. `EmployeeId` is a foreign key to the `Employee` table. Great. Now back to my original question, what are you looking to do in relation to this `EmployeeId`? Because your wording: `colors alternation based on EmployeeId` doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: If you want the row to be customized based on the contained data you need to define a DataTemplate. The AlternatingRowBackground property will only use the AlternationCount to determine color.